# SQL - combine two functions to one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have the first code which I use:

```
  with idlist as (
Select uniqueid as masterid
From table1
Union
Select uniqueid 
From table2 
)

Select i.masterid,
t1.*,
t2.*
From idlist as i
Left join table1 on t1.uniqueid = i.masterid
Left join table2 on t2.uniqueid = i.masterid
```

Purpose of the code above: to take 2 or more tables which have the same id column and union to one row.

Second code:

```
select [Id], [price], [description]
from [table1]
where name_1 % 10 = 8  -- enter name_1 manually
union all
select [Id], [price], [description]
from [table2]
where name_2 % 10 = 8
```

Purpose of the code above: check a specific column, if it ends with '8' then list its Id, price, description

**What I want**:
Basically combine those two codes. I need the second code to run **within** the result of the first code.
I thought of creating a new table for the result of the first query above, but as far as i know i need to create all the columns before inserting data into it, yet the result of the first query will be a combination of several tables which have a lot of different columns. 
Nonetheless, i still want the result of the combo between the two queries to be in a new table.

So if had to put everything to words and steps: 
Select id from tables> union under the same Id to one row with all their row content > create table with the result > run the second code above on the new table

Thanks

Comment: You could use a second CTE in the with statement to wrap the results, but it's not clear where table1 and table2 are coming from.

Comment: Table1 and table2 in the 2nd code are two from the tables i use in the first code (i originally use more than two)

Comment: I edited the first code in the post, hopefully its more clear now

Comment: Yes it became more clear. Is name_1, name_2 different for each select in the union? In which table is it located?

Comment: name1, name2 are both located in table1.

Comment: So if I understand it, every table table1, table2, table3, etc has both these two fields name_1 and name_2. But on the first select (on table1) you only check for name_1, and on the second select of the union (on table2) you only check for name_2. I don't see how it scales to many tables.

Comment: Ignore name 2, it is optional... if we create a table out of the result of the first code we can run the second code on it. i have added an explanation now at the bottom of my post. Appriciate the help

Comment: What results do you want?  It is not clear what you are really trying to do.  "the second code to run within the first" doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: "To run within the first" means that as if the result from the first code in my post is a new table. Basically perform the second query upon the first query result.. the first query combines between several tables and columns with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a bunch of columns from both tables, so I'm wondering if this accomplishes what you want:

```
select *
from (select t1.*
      from [table1] t1
      where name_1 % 10 = 8
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.*
      from [table2] t2
      where name_2 % 10 = 8
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Note that this is using `full join` -- which is what your first query is doing (well, assuming that `id` is not `NULL`).

Also, it seems very strange to be using an arithmetic calculation (`%`) on a column called "name".